# HTTP based actuator without regular web application in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a use case where I start up a custom server (call it foo) in spring boot. So the nature of the spring-boot is `WebApplicationType.NONE`. There can be the cases where I have the application in `WebApplicationType.SERVLET` (with Tomcat) mode along with `foo` server.

I want to reserve `server.port` for the HTTP application fixed and the `management.server.port` with some fixed values (both different values)

When I use the application with just `foo` server actuator should start on `management.server.port` with only one embedded instance of Tomcat. When I use `foo` and web server (tomcat) It should start 3 instances of servers (foo, regular tomcat embedded instance, management tomcat embedded instance)

In current setup if I set `management.server.port` with different value then `server.port` it starts its own embedded tomcat instance from `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration`

How do I keep the main server disabled when the need is just to use it for the actuator?